# Git diff does not syntax highlighted properly in sublime text editor 3

Tags: git, sublimetext3, diff

Recently I upgraded to sublime editor 3. I'm mostly using following command to view the `git diff`:

```
git diff | subl
```

The diff view works fine in my previous version. With Sublime 3, it does not work properly. The above command create a file `/tmp/subl\ stdin\ 0KWI2f.txt` and open it in a Sublime editor. Sublime treats it as text file. But diff works fine if I comes from sublime git gutter diff view.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: which previous version of ST did it work on? did it somehow save the temporary file with a different extension, or was it able to detect the syntax from the first line of the file? there is an open issue that suggests ST3 doesn't support stdin except on MacOS: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1236

Comment: I guess, it is ST3 beta. I could not find the way to change the temporary file to diff instead of txt. By the way, I use MacOS.